# How to update row on another sheet based on ID without overwriting with blank cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy rows from one sheet to another using Google Apps Script, based on a matching ID in Column 4 of each, but I can't seem to find how to paste it into the matching row and do this without overwriting existing data with blank cells.

In Google Sheets, Sheet1 contains rows of new data defined by an ID. Sheet2 should collect every single row, updating rows with the new data if the ID of the new row on Sheet1 matches an existing row on Sheet2. At the end of the day, Sheet1 is cleared, and all that remains is the most up-to-date info on each ID-item in Sheet2. Sometimes rows on Sheet1 aren't filled out completely, in which case, only the cells with data (from Sheet1) should be overwritten on Sheet2.

New IDs will be appended, but I've already more or less worked out how to do that, and it's not part of the question :)

```
function myFunction() {
    // Path to Correct Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3"); //temporary, while I work out how to copy it to the right row in Sheet2

  // Get size of ranges
  var header = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var data1 = range1.getValues();
  var range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var data2 = data2 = range2.getValues();

      Logger.log('data1 = ' + data1);

  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=header; n < data1.length ; n++){
    var keep = false;
    for(var p=header; p < data2.length ; p++){
      Logger.log(data1[n][0]+' =? '+data2[p][0]);
      if( data1[n][3] == data2[p][3]){
        resultArray.push(data1[n]);
        Logger.log('true');
        break ;
      }
    }
  }  
  sheet3.getRange(+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

I've managed to cobble together code that finds the matching IDs, and sends the entire row to Sheet3 (for now, before working out how to send it to the right row in Sheet2). But this overwrites any existing data with blank cells (if there are any), and I can't seem to make {contentsOnly: true} to work (is this even the right approach?)

I've only been doing this for a week, trying hard, but out of my depth. Any help, even just pointers in the right direction of topics to learn, would be greatly appreciated. Been living on stackoverflow for the past 48 hours straight trying to find something similar to this, but I couldn't find anything (maybe I'm not even searching the right thing!). Very humbling.

Comment: This is comparing column 4 not column 3 `if( data1[n][3] == data2[p][3])` arrays begin indexes at zero and columns on spreadsheet start at one.

Comment: Why are you using sheet3? Don't you want everything in Sheet2?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's column 4 in the google sheet. As I mentioned, I'm using Sheet3, because that is how I'm at least getting the function to copy the selected row somewhere, but ideally it would find the match in Sheet2 and copy it to the relevant row. That's my end game, though I'm not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var header = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var data1 = range1.getValues();
  var range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var data2 = data2 = range2.getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=header; n < data1.length ; n++){
    var keep = false;
    for(var p=header; p < data2.length ; p++){
      if( data1[n][3] == data2[p][3]){
        var tA=[];
        var rg=sheet2.getRange(p+1,1,1,sheet2.getLastColumn());
        for(var i=0;i<data1[0].length;i++) {
          tA.push((data1[n][i])?data1[n][i]:data2[p][i]);
        }
        rg.setValues([tA]);
        break ;
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Trying to decipher it now. It doesn't seem to work though, giving me `Cannot convert Array to Object[][].` for this line `rg.setValues(tA);` (I changed the 2s to 3s, to match the fact that it's in the fourth column, as per your previous comment.)

Comment: Share some data so I can debug it.

Comment: This is the test sheet I'm running this function on. Pretty sparse, but the aim is to use it as part of a personal task-manager. Sheet2 would collect all tasks ever, and Sheet1 is the day's sheet of new tasks. This is one small part of the whole (already have the calendar working, tasks, forms; still have a few details like this to polish).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZJ-9D5EwFgerqmda6EnHnW102XWBoWz-k6PiYCuCaZ0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just changed the code.  Copy it again. It's working now.  A few typo's and one command in the wrong place.  You also have to make sure that both Sheet1 and Sheet2 have six headers.  I used them to get the correct number of columns